# Javascript split array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array which contain the staff's Chinese and English names.

Example:

```
XXX MA Yo-Yo
```

Where `XXX` represents the Chinese name: `馬友友`.

I want to split this into two parts by using the 1st space `" "` as an indicator.

```
for (i = 0; i < /* ... */)
{
    w_temp = arr[i];
    w_name = w_temp[1].split(' ', 1);

    /* ... */
}
```

`w_name[0]` successfully returns `馬友友`. But `w_name[1]` returns `undefined`, which cannot return `MA Yo-Yo`.

How can I split it into two parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your existing `w_name = ...` line with something like this:

```
w_name = w_temp[1].split(' ');
w_name = [w_name[0], w_name.slice(1).join(' ')];
```

The `,1` you had earlier meant to stop parsing as soon as it came to the first space. This is not what you want; you want the part before the first space as one item and the part after as another. The new code parses all of the elements. After that, it sets it to an array consisting of:

1. The already-existing first element, and
2. The parts after the first element re-joined.

Comment: I think the `w_temp[1]` is an error. From the question, I think `w_temp` is the string "XXX CHAN Tai-Man"

Comment: @Phil: The question notes that `w_name[0]` returns the correct value, so `w_temp[1]` must be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
 split(' ', 1)
```

The 1 means to return at most one part.  You should just ommit that or change it to two if thats what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var w_temp = arr[i];

    // assuming w_temp contains an array where the second item
    // is the full name string
    var parts = w_temp[1].match(/^(.+?) (.+)$/);
    var cn_name = parts[1];
    var en_name = parts[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you invoke split method with `limit = 1`, then `w_name` has only 1 item.

In addition, yours input string has 2 whitespace, therefore, if you use split without limit parameter, `w_name` will contains 3 items ('XXX', 'CHAN', and 'Tai-Man').

I think you should use this:

```
var idx = str.indexOf(' ');
if (idx != -1) {
    var cn_name = str.substring(0, idx);
    var en_name = str.substring(idx + 1);
}
```